# Flask - send a bytes downloadable file

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, download

So I know you can use flask's `send_file` method that you choose a path on your computer but in my case, I need to read the file as bytes(because I am sending the file from a different python-client) So I have to send it as bytes and then the server would receive it. but I need to make it so some URL will download you this file can I just return the bytes and it will automatically download the file?
so something like this:

```
f = b""
with open("/somefile.txt", "rb") as some_file:
    f = some_file.read()

return f # and make this download the file that I read
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is an example adjusted from: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/streaming/
You need a generator function which yields the data, and then to call that function from the Response object.

```
from flask import Response 

@app.route("/")
def index():
    def generate():
        with open('somefile.txt','rb') as f:
            for row in f:
                yield row 
    return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/csv')
```

Then when you visit this route in the browser, you're immediately prompted to download the streaming data.

Comment: What is csv in mimetype? Do I need to specify the file type?

Comment: Say, my type is just `File` or `jpg` I need to do like `mimetype="jpg/csv"` or `mimetype="file/csv"`

Comment: It's `image/jpeg`, and `text/plain` for those two options.